# Understanding enumerate in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, enumerate, enumerated-types

I'm solving one python exercise and can't understand enumerate operation:
Can anyone tell me how this will work:

```
>>> a = [[('A', {}), 1, None, None, 0], [('B', {}), 1, None, None, 0]]
>>> b = [('A', {}), ('B', {})]
>>> for each in b:
...    my_idx = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(a) if a[idx][0] == each][0]
...    print my_idx
...
```

and the output it produces is:

```
0
1
```

To understand this, I did following changes:

```
>>> a = [[('A', {}), 1, None, None, 0], [('B', {}), 1, None, None, 0], [('A', {}), 1, None, None, 0], [('B', {}), 1, None, None, 0]]
>>> b = [('A', {}), ('B', {}), ('A', {}), ('B', {})]
>>> for each in b:
...    my_idx = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(a) if a[idx][0] == each][0]
...    print my_idx
...
```

and thought it should print:

```
0
1
2
3
```

but it produced:

```
0
1
0
1
```

Where I'm going wrong? How should I modify it to produce:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to solve? Also  `if val[0]` is the same as `if a[idx][0]`

Comment: given a and b, I'm trying to modify logic so that it will print 0 1 2 3 @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you want you need to change your logic:

```
[idx for idx, val in enumerate(a) if any(val[0] == x for x in b)]
```

When printed outputs:

```
print("\n".join([str(idx) for idx, val in enumerate(a) if any(val[0] == x for x in b)]))
0
1
2
3
```

You can also just test for membership using `in`:

```
print("\n".join([str(idx) for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val[0] in b]))

0
1
2
3
```

If  `val[0]` which corresponds to each tuple in the sublists of `a` is in `b` add the `idx` which is the index of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what `enumerate` does. It is just a special function, which will give you number of evelemt in array you are using in for.

```
for book in books:
    print book
for author in authors:
    print author
```

Will give you

```
Book A
Book B
Book C
Author A 
Author B
Author C
```

But if you need to count it, to make a handy list with numbers, you can use `enumerate`

```
for i, book in enumerate(books):
    print i, book
for i, author in enumerate(authors):
    print i, author
```

Will give you

```
1 Book A
2 Book B
3 Book C
1 Author A 
2 Author B
3 Author C
```

This is what `enumerate` does. It gives a nubmer to each element in array you are using. Nothing more.
If you want to create global counter, you should consider using global variable.